# nested lists sum of depth python

Tags: python, recursion

I am practicing recursion, and I want to return depth (starting from 1) for each element of the list (I already accomplished it), but also the weighted sum of the depth of nested list * the value.

For example, [1, [4]] -> (1 * 1) + (4 * 2) = 1 + 8 = 9

I am using the variable *res* to store the sum, but its restarting its counter every time it changes to a new list of lists. Is there a way to keep track of the sum as I did with the list?

```
nestedList = [[1,1],2,[1,1]]


def depth_checker(nested_list, depth=1, output=[], res=0):

  for i in nested_list:
    if not isinstance(i, list):
      output.append(depth)
      print(i, depth)
      res = res + (i * depth)
      print(res)
    elif isinstance(i, list):
      depth_checker(i, depth + 1, output, res)
  
  
  
  return (res, output)
```

Output

```
depth_checker(nestedList)


OUTPUT >>

1 2
2
1 2
4
2 1
2
1 2
4
1 2
6

(2, [2, 2, 1, 2, 2]])
```

Expected Output:

(10, [2, 2, 1, 2, 2])

Comment: Following your logic, it should be (9, [2, 2, 1, 2, 2]) = 2*1 + 2*1 + 1*1 + 2*1+2*1 isn't?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def depth_checker(nested_list, depth=1):
    res = 0
    for obj in nested_list:
        if isinstance(obj, list):
            res += depth_checker(obj, depth + 1)
        else:
            res += obj * depth
    return res


print(depth_checker([2, 2, 1, 2, 2])) # 9
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the difference between the implementation of a list and an integer.  When you make the recursive call to `depth_checker`, any changes to `output` will be reflected in the original variable.  However changes made to `res` will not modify the variable passed in.  Lists are mutable, integers aren't.

Your simplest option is to change your code to return the value `res` in all cases.  Then modify the last line to be `res = depth_checker(....)` so that it gets updated